# is there a way to set a var = to content of external file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, external, laravel-blade

I have to pass some result string to the view after sucessful ajax post. At the moment my js is placed in the view and the callback function creates a resultstring and then posts it to the results div. Since I have some blade syntax in the string that is being generated by the callback function it works until I leave the js in the blade.php view file, if I put the javascript in public/js/some.js blade doesn't parse that syntax and the result is the view is rendered with the syntax instead of data. So I was thinking: Can I put the sting in a separate view/js/result.blade.php and in the jquery function do somtehing like:

```
var resultStr = (content of view/js/result.blade.php)

for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){

    resultStr    

};

  $("#results").html(resultStr);
```

If so, how do I load the external file into partialstring?
My guess is that as it's a blade file it will be parsed.

---

@c-smile tried this code but is not working, the file is opened but then the view doesn't get the data

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('form');
        form.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.get("js/blade/filler.blade.php", function (data) {
                var resultStr = data;
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.prop('action'),
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = (data);
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                            resultStr;
                        }
                        $("#results").html(resultStr);

                    }

                });

            });

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's subject of AJAX functionality.

With jQuery you would do it as:

```
$.get( "view/js/result.blade.php", function( data ) {
  var resultStr = data;
  ...
});
```

Comment: i tried the code above but it's not working, it loads the file and output something but then stops with error 404